Can't read a custom settings JSON file
I added a custom JSON file with settings that I want to read in my .NET8 API. The standard appsettings.json file is read correctly but the custom secrets.json is not. The section I'm trying to read from it is always null. What am I doing wrong?
Program.cs:
var env = ConfigHelpers.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile("secrets.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build();

var configurationModel = config.GetSection(ConfigurationModel.SectionName).Get<ConfigurationModel>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(configurationModel);

var secretsConfigurationModel = config.GetSection(SecretsConfigModel.SectionName).Get<SecretsConfigModel>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(secretsConfigurationModel);

The class for reading from the standard appsettings.json file:
public class ConfigurationModel
{
    public const string SectionName = "AppConfig";
    public int SaverDelay { get; set; } = 10000;
    public int SaverBatchSize { get; set; } = 1000;
}

My custom class for reading from secrets.json:
public class SecretsConfigModel
{
    public const string SectionName = "Encryption";
    public string TokenSecretSalt { get; set; }
}

The secrets.json file:
{
  "Encryption": [
    { "TokenSecretSalt": "c48mt45ty487tg47y85mh8g5h6587h6g586gh568756" }
  ]
}


Note that "secrets.json" is used for "User Secrets" by Visual Studio, so you may be running into issues with that... I'd try a different file name and see if that does the trick.

I'm having a hard time reproducing your issue. https://dotnetfiddle.net/BpdF4q Please make sure you have a [mre].

verify your environment

@HereticMonkey, I've tried secretsApi.json and ran into the same problem.

@SachithWickramaarachchi, how do I verify the environment and how will it help with solving the issue?

@Val https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970594/asp-net-core-2-0-configurationtestsecret-always-return-null

@Val - you have an extra array nesting around your [ { "TokenSecretSalt": "c48mt45ty487tg47y85mh8g5h6587h6g586gh568756" } ] object.   This causes binding to fail, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/NbkWba.  Using Get<SecretsConfigModel []>() works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/b7GD1M.  Or remove the extra bracketing, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/DCvq33.

The value of the "Encryption" property in your secrets.json file is an array of objects:
{
  "Encryption": [ // Array start
    { "TokenSecretSalt": "c48mt45ty487tg47y85mh8g5h6587h6g586gh568756" }
  ] // Array end
}

You can use a collection to bind to it, e.g. SecretsConfigModel [] or List<SecretsConfigModel>:
var secretsConfigurationModel  = 
    config.GetSection(SecretsConfigModel.SectionName)
    .Get<SecretsConfigModel []>()
    .FirstOrDefault(); // Use SingleOrDefault() if there cannot be more than one.

Demo fiddle #1 here.
Alternatively you could eliminate the array nesting from your JSON and your current code will work:
{
  "Encryption": { 
    "TokenSecretSalt": "c48mt45ty487tg47y85mh8g5h6587h6g586gh568756" 
  }
}

Demo fiddle #2 here.

Damn, you're right! I don't know why I couldn't realize that. Your code works for me but I removed the [] so that I can use the simpler code to read the config. Thanks!
